# How to get every highlighted 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th line (starting at line 1 then +3) regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++, editpad

I have gotten the page source from Amazon and used Regex to find the names of the monitors I want. On amazon you can see 3 monitors per line with prices.  I essentially want the monitors at the start of each line which means every 1st, 4th line and so on.

```
https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Electronics-Computer-Monitors/zgbs/electronics/1292115011
```

My code is: `(?<='true'>\n\s+)\w.*.*(?=\n\s+</div>)`

How do I get every highlighted 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th line (starting at line 1 then +3) regex?  Maybe find and replace?

Comment: Your link is broken.  You should include the text you are trying to match directly in the question.  The question already has a bit of a smell, because it looks like you are trying to parse HTML using regex.  Instead, consider using an HTML parser.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Link should work now sorry about that

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Any recommendations?  Hmm, it appears java or python html parsers.  Looks like I'll be installing quite a lot

Comment: The link is still broken.  You have neglected my comment.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It works when I copy and paste it.  For some reason stack overflow seems to create an error

Comment: You are using EditPad Pro, I suggest you do not add Notepad++ tag to your question.

Comment: If this is for notepad++ as tagged before the edit: To identify the 1st, 4th, 7th item eg by the number. In np++ check the checkbox *. matches newline* and try regex like [`zg_rankNumber[^>]+>\s*\b(?:[147]|1[0369]|2[258])\b.*?'true'>\s*\K[^<]*[^<\s]`](https://regex101.com/r/Hnum3C/1) where [`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thank you.  I tried that in notepad++ and editpad and it gave me an error.  In notepad++ I got Search "zg_rankNumber[^>]+>\s*\b(?:[147]|1[0369]|2[258])\b.*?'true'>‌​\s*\K[^<]*[^<\s]" (0 hits in 0 files)

Comment: @bobblebubble I will try and modify it to see if it works in editpadpro.  \k is not supported so have to use something else

Comment: Hmm have been trying to modify.. not really sure how to use a \K alternative as it just does not work in my job.  I also am not too sure how to get every nth match either.  I will keep on digging...

Comment: If your tool supports lookbehind of variable length, try something like `(?<=_(?:[147]|1[0369]|2[258])\?[^>]*>(?:<[^>]*>\s*){3}<[^>]*'true'>\s*)\b[^<]*[^<\s]`

Comment: @bobblebubble Hmmm no such luck.  Did it work for you in editpad?  I'll try and change around a few things

Comment: Na it worked for me in [regexstorm tool](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester).

Comment: @bobblebubble Uh okay.  I think a lot of regex editors vary in capabilities I guess.  Hopefully I can get it working in editpadpro as the job I have tends to have capabilities similar to that.

Comment: @bobblebubble Are there any guides on getting nth line of a match or something of the sort.  Might help me work out what to change.

Comment: You're parsing html. if you view the source you see, it's not nth line you need but all 3 enumerated items. You need an identifier from source (I used the link or the rank number in first regex).

Comment: @bobblebubble I can't really understand how [147]|1[0369]|2[258] represent anything I'm viewing in the source. Or how that would get every 3rd?  Sorry

Comment: In first pattern I used `zg_rankNumber` in second pattern this part from link `/ref=zg_bs_1292115011_1?`, `/ref=zg_bs_1292115011_4?`, `/ref=zg_bs_1292115011_7?` (it's a responsive website. scale your broswerwindow and you have two rows instead three. You need some item-number from source to get each 3rd item.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks.  Are there any guides online or anywhere you can point me to in the right direction so I can use this.  I understand what you're saying but I feel like I would not be able to replicate.

Comment: You can download [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.4.2.html) and use [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/Hnum3C/1). If you need a regex tutorial, try [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) or see the [SO regex faq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5527985). Wish you good luck.